# C++ file segmentation fault 11 in segment tree

Tags: c++, memory, tree

I was implementing the segment tree class and it can be compiled successfully. However, when I was running with some test cases, it always throws an error like "segmentation fault 11". If I run it on the OJ, it throws like:

### Line 60: member access within misaligned address 0x000000000005 for type 'struct SumTree', which requires 8 byte alignment

Can someone help me with this please? I think maybe it's related to the memory allocation, and even I used

```
memset(left,0,sizeof(left));
```

it still doesn't work. I am not so good at memory allocation in C++, if you can, please refer me some materials on this for me to learn.

Thank you!

Code:

```
struct SumTree {
    int val,start,end;
    SumTree* left;
    SumTree* right;
    SumTree(int a, int b): val(0), start(a), end(b), left(NULL), right(NULL) {

    }
};

class NumArray {
public:
    NumArray(vector<int> nums) {
        size=nums.size();
        root=buildTree(nums,0,size-1);
    }

    void update(int i, int val) {
        update(root,i,val);
    }

    int sumRange(int i, int j) {
        i=max(i,0);
        j=min(j,size-1);
        return getSum(i,j,root);
    }
private:
    int size;
    SumTree* root;
    SumTree* buildTree(vector<int> nums, int a, int b) {
        SumTree* root=new SumTree(a,b);
        if (a==b) {
            root->val=nums[a];
            return root;
        }
        int mid=a+(b-a)/2;
        root->left=buildTree(nums,a,mid);
        root->right=buildTree(nums,mid+1,b);
        root->val=root->left->val+root->right->val;
        return root;
    }
    int update(SumTree* root, int index, int k) {
        int diff;
        if (root->start==index && root->end==index) {
            diff=k-root->val;
            root->val=k;
            return diff;
        }
        int mid=root->start+(root->end-root->start)/2;
        if (mid<index) {
            diff=update(root->right,index,k);
        }
        else {
            diff=update(root->left,index,k);
        }
        root->val+=diff;
        return diff;
    }
    int getSum(int a, int b, SumTree* root) {
        int res=0;
        if (root->start==a && root->end==b) return root->val; // Line 60
        int mid=root->start+(root->end-root->start)/2;
        if (mid<a) return getSum(a,b,root->right);
        if (mid>=b) return getSum(a,b,root->left);
        return getSum(a,mid,root->left)+getSum(mid+1,b,root->right);
    }
};
```

Comment: What does "I used `memset(left,0,sizeof(left));`" mean ?
 Where did you use it? What did you use it for?
 `memset(left,0,sizeof(left));` already looks strange. The first parameter is typically a pointer, the second - size of *pointed object*. I.e. normally one'd have `memset(left,0, sizeof *left);`. However, it is not clear why you are using `memset` at all. And which line is "line 60"?

Comment: Not familiar with that error message, but "address 0x000000000005"  looks creepy. Null pointer somewhere?

Comment: @AnT I am not using memset in the code. I tried it but failed, for I was guessing it's due to the memory allocation. (Also, I know my memset format is wrong, just give an example...)

Comment: @user4581301 Maybe it's the OJ system's error message. But when I ran it on my own laptop, it gives segmentation fault.
I set SumTree's left and right pointers to NULL.

Comment: How does a node get new left and right branches in your code? All I can see is branches initialised to NULL in the constructor, and then never modified. You also never check them for NULL. Do you expect your tree to be infinite?

Comment: You never set `root` and you never add any branches to the tree.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you for pointing out that, I have added one line in my NumArray constructor like ## root=builTree() ##, but now it's still segmentation fault 11.

Comment: @davidchai21 Read n.m.’s comment more carefully. Also read your code more carefully.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you and n.m. so much! I finally got to know that I made a stupid mistake in the buildTree() function... Now it works.